# error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I add the models when using rust diesel as ORM like this:

```
use rocket::serde::Serialize;
use rocket::serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Insertable, Serialize, Queryable, Deserialize,Default)]
#[table_name = "dict"]
pub struct QueryEdict {
    pub id: i64,
    pub word: String,
    pub phonetic: String,
    pub definition: String,
    pub translation: String,
    pub pos: String,
    pub collins: String,
    pub oxford: String,
    pub tag: String,
    pub bnc: i32,
    pub frq: i32,
    pub exchange: String,
    pub detail: String,
    pub audio: String,
}
```

and generate `scheme.rs` like this:

```
table! {
    dict (id) {
        word -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        phonetic -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        definition -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        translation -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        pos -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        collins -> Nullable<Int4>,
        oxford -> Nullable<Int4>,
        tag -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        bnc -> Nullable<Int4>,
        frq -> Nullable<Int4>,
        exchange -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        detail -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        audio -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        id -> Int4,
    }
}
```

the `main.rs` look like this:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

mod schema;
mod models;

#[get("/<id>")]
fn index(id:&str) -> &'static str {
    return "ok";
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index])
}
```

and this is the dependencies:

```
[package]
name = "rust-learn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.64", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.64"
serde_derive = "1.0"
# database
diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
jsonwebtoken = "7"
chrono = "0.4"
```

when I build the project, shows error like this:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `dict`
 --> src/models.rs:5:16
  |
5 | #[table_name = "dict"]
  |                ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `dict`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `rust-learn`
```

am I missing something? what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: I think you missing the reference to the table: `use whatever::scheme::dict;`

Comment: I had a problem like this when I was compiling wasm, this might be unrelated but my error looked very similar. Could it be that you don't have the correct "target" installed? What fixed my problem was running "rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown" Is there some target that you're missing?

Comment: I remember it was missing some package import, so check your code and make sure  the package imported correctly. I my situation, it is not about the target problem.@ChristianOConnor